# .htaccess, how to combine and add language to path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having trouble combining multiple rules. I just can't figure how to write in `.htaccess`.

My `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) web/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How would I combine these? Now only the first rule works `web/$1`.

And also how can I add one extra redirect to language with all this?

To clarify what i would like to do:

- **user writes `example.com`** since my index file is in `/web` of root it goes there (this works)
- **now it should redirect him to `www.example.com`** not working
- **after that add `/en` to URL so that it looks like `www.example.com/en`** -  can't figure out yet.

I have checked other questions but I really don't understand how it works, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you have the directives in the wrong order. You should be *redirecting* to `www.example.com` before *rewriting* to `web/<whatever>`.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect example.com to www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Internally rewrite to "web" subdirectory.
RewriteRule (.*) web/$1 [L]
```

I'm assuming you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/web` subdirectory that also uses mod_rewrite - otherwise the last directive would result in a rewrite loop.

> after that add `/en` to url so that it looks like `www.example.com/en`

You need to do that *before* you rewrite the URL to the `web` subdirectory. I assume you could be requesting `www.example.com/<page>` and this should redirect to `www.example.com/en/<page>`?

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect example.com to www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302,L]

# Redirect to "/en" if not already present at the start of the URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/en/$1 [R=302,L]

# Internally rewrite to "web" subdirectory.
RewriteRule (.*) web/$1 [L]
```

The `RewriteCond` directive checks that the URL-path does not (`!`) start with `/en/` before redirecting.

Note I've changed the redirects to 302 (temporary). Test with 302s first before using 301s to avoid browser caching issues. And be sure to clear your browser cache before testing.